# Is there a way to automatically feed a label after each print, then automatically backfeed that fed label before the next print in Zebra printers?

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl, thermal-printer

I apologize for the long title, but that is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

I'll try to explain more briefly here:
So I have a Zebra ZT610 with a scanner that checks every single label as they are printed. The problem is that we're trying to print labels solely, not in batch, and the issue with that is that the printed label will always be in a position where an operator will not be able to take the label without destroying it. The issue with this is it will become a waste of labels and ribbons if this process remains as is.

How it is now (it is not really in production, but to give you an imagination):

1. Operator clicks on print
2. Zebra prints a label (and the scanner checks the label simultaneously)
3. Operator feeds a label (in order to take the label without destroying it)
4. Operator takes the label
5. Repeat the process

That is the issue, in theory we would have to waste HALF of the amount of available labels (assuming that all printed labels passed the inspection) in order to finish the job, which is definitely absurd and no one in the world would do this hahah

What we're trying to achieve:

1. Operator clicks on print
2. Zebra prints a label (and the scanner checks the label simultaneously)
3. The printer feeds a label automatically (or maybe half of a label at least for the printed label to be taken without any issue or destroying it)
4. Operator takes the label
5. Operator prints another label
6. Printer backfeeds the latest fed label
7. Printer prints on the backfed label
8. Continue on from step 3, and so on.

I searched for anything related to this and all what i found was this:

```
^XA  
^FD  
^XZ
```

All it basically those is "print" a space on a label, thus technically feeding a label. But i was never able to get that label to go back inside the printer.

Thank you for reading this far.

EDIT:

We have also tried this:

1. Went into the printers settings via its IP address and login
2. Click on 'View and Modify Printer Settings'
3. Click on 'General Setup'
4. Below you will find 'Tear Off Adjust', we've set it to the maximum (120) but that was not enough, it is still too far inside.

But i hope the solution above helps other people out there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `~JS` command - Change Backfeed Sequence.  By overriding the default backfeed, you can force the label media to feed forward after printing, then retract on the next print.

Not knowing how much backfeed you will need, start with 50% (`~JS50`) and adjust from there.

Comment: I tried that, it only changes the printers backfeed settings and sadly the values provided are not enough.